# How to take screenshot (video) of Linux plymouth theme

Tags: linux, video, screenshot

I want to know how to take video screenshot of Linux plymouth theme, I meant the proper way. Recently I used plymouth-x11 to show the preview of plymouth theme, but it didn't work well because the position of the background and other images were not the exact same as the real one.

Regards and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Try http://superuser.com

Comment: ...or http://unix.stackexchange.com, or http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is best done from a virtual machine.  If you can install Linux in VirtualBox and load your Plymouth theme there, it is trivial to take a screenshot from the host OS.